# Are there any grounds not to use while in python

Tags: python, while-loop, do-while

One of my teachers warned me not to use `while` in python. It is really strange for me as I have not found any articles on why to do so. What do you think on what could the grounds be?

Comment: Terrible advice. I'd be interested to hear the teacher's explanation!

Comment: for loops are just as useful but sometimes you need to use a while thats bad advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the control statement that best suits your needs in each situation.

An advice like "Don't use while, only use for" boils down to "If the only tool you know is a hammer, all problems look like a nail."